# Cannot run Assembly code produced by g++

Tags: assembly

I used a very simple C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 9;
    int b = 4;

    cout << (a+b) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Then in terminal, created Assembly code using g++ -S flag:

```
g++ a.cpp -S
```

This produces a file named a.s . I tried to run this Assembly code using nasm:

```
nasm -f elf a.s
```

But this results in tons of error. (mainly this one -> error: parser: instruction expected
)

I also tried with

```
-masm=intel
```

option.

So, why does not that piece of Assembly code (which is produced by g++ through a running C++ code) work?

Comment: Because `g++` does not produce `nasm` syntax assembly. It only works with gnu assembler (`as`).

Comment: compile it with g++ as you would with a c++ source file i.e `g++ a.s -o prog` (g++ will then use `as` as above poster mentioned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually GNU assembler `as` works with this format.

`as a.s`

The output of `as` is an object file. To make it executable you need to link it with `ld` but you will also need to link in any objects it depends on, which if the source was generated from `gcc`, will at least include libc, as well as probably some other object files, but, as James's comment contains, it might be easier to just do

```
g++ a.s -o prog
```